# I have an Pojo Kotlin Object which contains list, child objects and sub child objects and I need to change the value of a field using field name

Tags: java, kotlin

Example given classes as below

```
data class Book (
  var name: String? = null,
  var codes: List<Code>? = null,
  var description: Description? = null
)
    
data class Code(
  var value: String? = null
  var date: String? = null
)
    
data class Description(
  var notes: String? = null
)
```

I am looking a util where I can change the value of the given field name.

For example: I need to change the date value of Code class using field name "date". I am looking at generic util class which we can use to change the value at any given child class or list or map....which matches the give string name

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any existing utils for that purpose.
A very simple method you could use would be a Jackson object mapper:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> setProperty(c: T, propName: String, value: Any?): T {
    val map = jacksonObjectMapper().convertValue<Map<String, Any?>>(c).toMutableMap()
    map[propName] = value
    return jacksonObjectMapper().convertValue(map)
}
```

Then you can for instance write the following to set the date value of a `Code` object:

```
val code = Code("x", "y")
val resultCode = setProperty(code, "date", "z")
```

But please note that this has very bad performance since it converts the data class to json, then to a map, then again to json, and finally back into the data class. It is also not very good because it creates a new object each time you change one property.

---

A bit better would be to use Kotlin reflection like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

fun <T : Any> setProp(c: T, propName: String, value: Any?) {
    val prop = getMutableProperty(c, propName)
    val type = prop.setter.parameters[1].type
    if (value == null && !type.isMarkedNullable) error("property $propName is not nullable")
    prop.setter.call(c, value)
}

fun <T: Any> getMutableProperty(c: T, propName: String): KMutableProperty<*> {
    val prop = c::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == propName } ?: error("no property $propName")
    if (prop !is KMutableProperty<*>) error("property $propName is not mutable")
    return prop
}
```

This can be used to change the property of a data class without creating a new element on each changed property which would look like this:

```
val code = Code("x", "y")
setProp(code, "date", "myval")
println(code) // now prints Code(value=x, date=myval)
```

Comment: In my case fun <T : Any> setProp(c: T, propName: String, value: Any?) c:T is a list

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean. Can you please extend your question by some concrete examples of different objects and their properties that you want to access?

Comment: I have list of Book class and it contains different classes or structs and I need to search the entire class and identify given field name and set a different value to that field.